# c# gridview receive right value

Tags: c#, gridview

Currently this is my way and query for connecting to a gridview:

```
  gridItems.DataSource = sqlDisplayContent.connectDataTable("select (g.gerecht) AS dispValue,b.gerechtId from besteld  as b inner join gerechten g on b.gerechtId=g.gerechtId where reserveringId='"+reserveringId+"'");
```

I want to receive (when I click it) b.gerechtId.
Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
int row = gridItems.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        string reserveringNr = gridItems.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, reserveringNr);
```

But I want to receive b.gerechtId.

What's the propper way to receive b.gerechtId? And how can I only show the dispValue in the gridview?

I know with a combobox you can use DisplayMember and ValueMember. 
Is there something like that but than for a gridview?

Thanks.

Comment: change the `Cells[0]` to that index or use by name like `Cell["columnName"]`

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!